# Usage of function.prototype.bind() on EventListeners

Tags: javascript, events

i have seen this code:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (bind) {
    var self = this;
    return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return self.apply(bind || null, args);
    };
};
```

in some implementation on javascript and used for handle EventListener

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mykeydownhandler.bind(this), false);
```

can explain me this functionality

Comment: It's simply binding the `mousedown` event to the handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just a homebrew implementation of the standard [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

> Creates a new function that, when called, itself calls this function in the context of the provided `this` value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function was called.

That should be wrapped with some sort feature detection so that it only gets used for browsers with a behind-the-times JavaScript engine.

The problem with just saying this:

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mykeydownhandler, false);
```

Is that `this.mykeydownhandler` is an unbound function and the value of `this` inside that function will be determined when it is called. So, if `mykeydownhandler` depends on what `this` is then you won't have the right context when the event is triggered. When you say this:

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mykeydownhandler.bind(this), false);
```

using either the native `bind` or the homebrew replacement in your question, the `this` in the `addEventListener` call will be the same as `this` inside `mykeydownhandler`.

Comment: yes, but why would anyone ever want to do `this.functionname.bind(this)`.  The function is already bound to "this", is it not?  Why do we need to create a new function bound to `this` (by calling `bind()`)?

Comment: @Cheeso: No, the function is not bound to its object. `var x = o.m` gives you an **unbound** method, `m`, stored in `x`, the `this` will be determined when you say `x()`. That's why we have [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and `bind` and why [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has a `context` parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, it makes sure that the `this` keyword within the event handler function is set correctly in all browsers. Some browsers don't seem to get it right.

I avoid the `this` problem by using closures and more reliable variables, but this is an alternative method of achieving the same result.