# TypeError: Result of expression near '...}.bind(this))...' [undefined] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am getting a Safari only error: TypeError: Result of expression near '...}.bind(this))...' [undefined] is not a function.

These are lines 88-92:

```
$(this.options.work).each(function(i, item) {
  tmpItem = new GridItem(item);
  tmpItem.getBody().appendTo($("#" + this.gridId));
  this.gridItems.push(tmpItem);
}.bind(this));
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Older versions of Safari don't support `bind`. If you try this (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dKbFh/):

```
console.log(typeof Function.prototype.bind == 'function');
```

you'll get `false` in older Safaris but `true` in the latest Firefox and Chrome. I'm not sure about Opera or IE but there is a compatibility list (which may or may not be accurate):

> http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

You can try to patch your own version in with [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949129/usage-of-function-prototype-bind-on-eventlisteners/7949163):

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (bind) {
    var self = this;
    return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return self.apply(bind || null, args);
    };
};
```

but check if `Function.prototype.bind` is there first.

Comment: @Antti: Good call, [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) has a `bind` implementation as well.

Answer (score 1):

or for a `bind` shim supporting partial application:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function(o /*, args */) {
        // Save the this and arguments values into variables so we can // use them in the nested function below.
        var self = this, boundArgs = arguments;
        // The return value of the bind() method is a function 
        return function() {
            // Build up an argument list, starting with any args passed
            // to bind after the first one, and follow those with all args // passed to this function.
            var args = [], i;
            for(i = 1; i < boundArgs.length; i++) args.push(boundArgs[i]); 
            for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) args.push(arguments[i]);
            // Now invoke self as a method of o, with those arguments
            return self.apply(o, args); 
        };
    }; 
}
```